# Read csv from url

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv url which works correctly if simply pasted into a browser:

```
http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=JSE%3AMTN&startdate=Nov 1, 2011&enddate=Nov 30, 2011&output=csv
```

However I can't seem to download the csv using pandas. I get the error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPERROR: HTTP ERROR 400: Bad Request
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():

    url = 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=JSE%3AMTN&startdate=Nov 1, 2011&enddate=Nov 30, 2011&output=csv'

    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    print(df)
```

Please could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That URL is not properly encoded. Your browser automagically replaces the spaces `' '` by `'%20'`, the underlying `urllib` request from the python standard library doesn't do that. Replace all spaces by `'%20'` and you are fine.

Also, if you are using pandas 0.16 you can skip all of this since support for Google Finance data is built in now (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-google):

```
import pandas.io.data as web

df = web.DataReader("F", 'JSE:MTN', "2011-11-01", "2011-11-30")
```

Comment: Thanks @filmor I figured something like that was probably the issue. I have replaced the spaces with %20 however I am now getting the error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 8: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: That's really great that this is now built into pandas. Do you know what the 'F' parameter is for? When I try to print the dataframe after requesting 'JSE:MTN' I get 'None'. However if I try 'google' then it works. I think it's got something to do with the 'F' parameter but can't find any documentation on how to specify the exchange and stock symbol

Comment: Cool I got it to work. Thanks for your help. This works: web.DataReader('JSE:MTN', 'google', start, end)

Comment: Ah, maybe I misinterpreted the documentation, it is maybe the other way round, i.e. `"JSE:MTN", "google"`.

Comment: Regarding your first issue: Somehow you have managed to insert a [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://decodeunicode.org/u+FEFF) character after the `"http:"`. Just retype that part and you are fine, URLs are ASCII-only strings.